# DB2 - ODBC Connection protocol specific error code 10061

Tags: db2, odbc, database-administration

I installed DB2 FP 10.1 32-bit ODBC Driver on Windows 7 (64-bit) from the following URL

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418043

I created a 'System DSN' and configured the following parameters

```
Hostname   xxxxxx2x  (DB2 server running on UNIX)
Port       5xxxx     (Port is on state 'LISTENING')
Database   dxxx
DBAlias    dxxx
Protocol   TCP / IP
```

And when I 'Connect' (Test Connection) from ODBC, I get the following error

```
SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected.  
Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used:
"SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected. Protocol specific error code(s) 10061. sqlstate=08001
```

To me settings are correct, not sure what am I missing

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the System DSN? Windows 7 64-bit will create the DSN under the 64-bit ODBC Data Source Admin by default. I think I've had better luck creating it under the 32-bit version, which can be found at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.

Comment: Yes, I created it via odbcad32.exe